# What's the most intuitive graph to display the largest changes?

Tags: data, graphs

I was thinking of implementing a column chart with two bars for each item displaying the current month and the previous month values.

Comment: I came across this only yesterday: [Choosing a good chart](http://extremepresentation.typepad.com/blog/2006/09/choosing_a_good.html)

Comment: @RogerAttrill - I think you should post that in answer form. Run through it and cite the answer it gives for the OP's situation. Certainly a worthwhile contribution- IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Candle Stick bar charts](http://stockcharts.com/school/doku.php?id=chart_school:chart_analysis:introduction_to_candlesticks) with x-axis being time & y-axis being dollar would be a suitable graph.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart

Answer (score -1):

Stock prices do it with high low bar.  It is pretty much the standard practice from even before computers.

Comment: Can you link to an image to make it clearer what you mean?  Also, can you cite any evidence to support your assertion that it is a "standard practice"?

Comment: @3nafish Really you have never seen a stock high low for the day chart?

Comment: @Paparazzi - they aren't confused about what you are referring to. They are pointing out how to make you answer self contained, and better as a result. Also, for clarification on your assertion that such a graph is a "standard" for displaying such data - which is a reasonable request.